# Why "Android N WebView signatures" has changed

Tags: android, webview, android-7.0-nougat

While I was working on hook, I found that the signature of the Android N "com.google.android.webview" PackageInfo changed. Why is there a change? Android N what changes? When did the signature change?

Comment: Should probably dig into the documentation/source for comparison. Hopefully google documented it in the dev site.

Answer (score 0):

Android n in the WebViewFactory more than a verifyPackageInfo method, the signature verification, but will not modify the signature